# Token Based Authentication - Security vulnerability?

Tags: angularjs, jwt

We are doing an Html5 AngularJS application. We are using token based authentication. The authentication process logs the user in then a JWT Token is returned to the application which is stored in sessionStorage.

We requested a security audit on the application and the tester said that it is a big problem that the token is stored in the sessionStorage. Because he can copy the token and impersonate a user from another device.

Where and how should I store this token to make sure that it is secure ? Is it even a risk leaving it in the session storage since the hacker would need access to the actual device to perform this attack

regards

Comment: AFAIK, anyone can trace the token if you store the token in local in any way (session storage, local storage, cookie, JSON) and send to subsequent calls but we can increase the security level in service side (for eg: Allowing request from the same domain, token expiration logic..etc..,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to increase security on token storage is to store  the token in a Cooke with the HttpOnly flag set. This would mean the token could only be accessed when your app makes http requests.